# Google Sheets formula to round up columns to nearest thousand and sum

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

So i have a column with numbers and want to sum the column, but i want them to be rounded up to the nearest thousand.

```
=SUM(ARRAYFORMULA(ROUNDUP(J4:J ,-3)))
```

I tried this however I am just getting a `Formula parsing error`.

The goal is for this:

```
100
900
5600
```

To give me `8000`.

Comment: It works for me here. Perhaps you have content on column J that is triggering an error message that ROUNDUP cannot digest. (see it working here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SmKszn5VnQ4lNo9jEKKVtN_Yv6arFmxqn2aQ12aMlic/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

A parse error indicates a syntax issue in a formula. The formula you quote should work fine in the United States locale.

In the event your locale uses commas as decimal separators, replace the comma `,` in the formula with a semicolon `;`.